# Error summing 2 different rasters?

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator

I was trying to sum two different rasters and the final outcome is an error (image attached below)?
The main goal is to sum the values of each pixel in those rasters (both raster files have the same size and pixel size), for that i was using raster calculator, with a simple expression the "TIPO_SOLO@1" + "declives_map_reclass@1", but probably i doing some steps wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, i was able to produce a raster that contains the sums of both rasters. it´s seems that by default the output raster was coming in Raster Matrix Format, but if i change it for GeoTiff, it´s produces the final result perfectly.

[image]